# ¿Comó colocar estilos a mis tablas exportadas con la libreria xlsx.js? jquery 3.6.4

Tags: javascript, css, excel, tablas, diseño

Actualmente estoy exportando un excel de una tabla generada en HTML, todo estoy haciéndolo en código JavaScript. Pero no consigo que se descargue mi excel con diseño.
Encontre una libreria que me exporta con diseño pero no multi Hojas, en cambio esta libreria si me deja exportar varias hojas en el excel pero sin diseño. Necesito su ayuda por favor.

Aqui les dejo mi codigo javaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#exportarExcel").click(function () {
          var table = document.getElementById('tablaCartera_Ventas');
          var table_det1 = document.getElementById('TablaDetalleSemana0');
          var table_det2 = document.getElementById('TablaDetalleSemana1');
          var table_det3 = document.getElementById('TablaDetalleSemana2');
          var table_det4 = document.getElementById('TablaDetalleSemana3');
          var table_det5 = document.getElementById('TablaDetalleSemana4');
          //creo hojas de excel por cada tabla
          var data = {
                 'REPORTE CARTERA': tableToData(table),
                 'DETALLE S1': tableToData(table_det1),
                 'DETALLE S2': tableToData(table_det2),
                 'DETALLE S3': tableToData(table_det3),
          };

          if (table_det4) {
                 data['DETALLE S4'] = tableToData(table_det4);
          }

          if (table_det5) {
                 data['DETALLE S5'] = tableToData(table_det5);
          }
          let filename = 'Reporte_Cartera';

          var workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
          // Itera sobre cada hoja y agregarla al libro de trabajo
          Object.keys(data).forEach(function (sheetName) {
                 var worksheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(data[sheetName]);
                 XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, sheetName);
          });
          // Descargar el archivo Excel
          XLSX.writeFile(workbook, filename + '.xlsx');

   });

   function tableToData(table) {
          var data = [];
          $(table).find('tbody tr').each(function () {
                 var rowData = [];
                 $(this).find('td').each(function () {
                        rowData.push($(this).text());
                 });
                 data.push(rowData);
          });
          return data;
   }
```

});